# не могу найти скачиваемые коды чаптеров книжки lightweight_django

Tags: python, django, git, github

[https://github.com/lightweightdjango/examples.git][1]

и через README.rst попробовал скачать первый чаптер, через соответствующий ему линк:
https://github.com/lightweightdjango/examples/tree/chapter-1 , но не вышло, где можно было бы найти?

Comment: Что не вышло? Ссылка рабочая, кнопка Download ZIP присутствует.

Comment: через ЗИП да, но я хотел склонировать

Comment: Склонируй через git

Comment: Проблема в том, что ссылок на отдельные чаптеры нету для гита, потому тут подходит вариант только если делать через ЗИП

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главы тут в ветках, ветки клонируются с параметром -b

git clone https://github.com/lightweightdjango/examples.git -b chapter-1  chapter-1

Можно переключать на скаченном через checkout -b  chapter-1

Comment: Окей, так понял, попробую

Comment: склонировал также как вы написали, и сработало, но возник один вопрос: "а зачем писать chapter-1 второй раз?", хотелось бы понимать внутренню механику такого запроса

Comment: Просто почему не пишется chapter-1?

Comment: Отдельный каталог